# How can I avoid the "warning: redefining module Foo" when running ExUnit tests multiple times in one process

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I wish to be able to run the ExUnit tests multiple times from within a running process, such as `iex`.

To do this I have code that looks somewhat like this:

```
def test do
  # Unload test files
  ["test"]
  |> Mix.Utils.extract_files("*")
  |> Enum.map(&Path.expand/1)
  |> Code.unload_files

  # Reenable tasks
  ~w(loadpaths deps.loadpaths test)
  |> Enum.map(&Mix.Task.reenable/1)

  # Run the test suite
  Mix.Task.run("test", args)

  # Cleanup
  :elixir_config.put(:at_exit, [])
end
```

This works, but prints the `test/my_app/foo_test.exs:1 warning: redefining module FooTest` for each module defined in my test files.

I thought that as I had unloaded those files from the `:elixir_code_server` these warnings would not be raised, but this is not the case.

How might I silence or avoid these warnings without resorting to methods such as silencing stderr?

It seems there is a compiler flag that I can use to suppress these warnings, but there is no clear public API for setting this flag.
It seems we can disable these warning messages, there there is no clear API for doing so.

See `elixir_compiler:get_opt/1`
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_compiler.erl#L8-L13

See `elixir_module:check_module_availability/3` where it checks `elixir_compiler:get_opt(ignore_module_conflict)`
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_module.erl#L408-L418

Comment: Unloading doesn't help, because loaded modules and defined modules are two different things. If you open fresh console and type `Ex <tab>` it won't show you `ExUnit`, because it is not loaded, but it is defined. If you type `ExUnit.non_existent_fun` it will load the `ExUnit` and it will be in the shell. I think your best option would be to skip mix and run ExUnit directly. There is an `recompile` command in iex anyway, so you would only need to start the  tests.

Comment: If I run ExUnit directly I still need to handle recompilation of the test files, which still results in the same warning messages. Do you know how to avoid these?

Answer (score 13):

After some trial-and-error storming, this is the solution that works for me:

```
Code.compiler_options(ignore_module_conflict: true)
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is the correct answer, although it should be `ignore_module_conflict:true` when you need to turn it off temporarily, and `false` when you want to turn it back on.

Answer (score -1):

This might do it:

```
mix test --no-compile
```

or in your case, set args to include `--no-compile` like so:

```
 # Run the test suite
 Mix.Task.run("test","--no-compile")
```

NB: I'm not able to test that code for correctness right now so if it's wrong, apologies in advance.

Comment: If modules are not recompiled there's no point in running the tests multiple times as nothing will have changed. I unload the files so that recompilation is triggered the second time.